# VBA checkboxes in the wrong place

Tags: vba, checkbox

I've copied a `VBA` code from `on-line` to produce `checkboxes` within a range and link them to adjacent cells. The linked cells are in the correct place however the check boxes appear offset up and left by a few cells? I can't see anything in the code that might cause this? I'm working on a `mac`.

Thanks for any help,
Aaron

```
Option Explicit
Sub insertCheckboxes()

  Dim myBox As CheckBox
  Dim myCell As Range

  Dim cellRange As String
  Dim cboxLabel As String
  Dim linkedColumn As String

  cellRange = InputBox(Prompt:="Cell Range", _
    Title:="Cell Range")

  linkedColumn = InputBox(Prompt:="Linked Column", _
    Title:="Linked Column")

  cboxLabel = InputBox(Prompt:="Checkbox Label", _
    Title:="Checkbox Label")

  With ActiveSheet
    For Each myCell In .Range(cellRange).Cells
      With myCell
        Set myBox = .Parent.CheckBoxes.Add(Top:=.Top, _
          Width:=.Width, Left:=.Left, Height:=.Height)

        With myBox
          .LinkedCell = linkedColumn & myCell.Row
          .Caption = cboxLabel
          .Name = "checkbox_" & myCell.Address(0, 0)
        End With

        .NumberFormat = ";;;"
      End With

    Next myCell
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Works fine for me (although on Windows).

Comment: After messing around with it i have figured out it only messes up like this in page view. Which is a pain because i would like my document locked into page view

Answer (score 0):

Apologies responding to a comment with an answer, unfortunately, my respect isn't high enough to comment.

However, you could set `ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView` while the macro is running and set `ActiveWindow.View = xlPageLayoutView` before the sub ends.

I should be able to respond to any comments on this answer, so I'll be able to assist if the above doesn't resolve your issue.